# ORA-01722: invalid number error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running the below mentioned query in my Oracle client and i am getting

> ORA-01722: invalid number

error. I know the issue is due to the TAG_VALUE column being of type "`varchar2`" and i am converting it to number and then using that field in where clause. I have tried using "`CAST`" function but that is also not helping.
If i run the query neglecting the last where condition with code `WHERE (P.TAG_VALUE > '100')` then i am getting the result but including the last where clause gives me error.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
      count(P.CREATED_DATETIME)
    FROM
      ( 
      select OUTPUT_TAG_ID,TO_NUMBER(TAG_VAL,'9999.99') AS 
    TAG_VALUE,TAG_VAL_TS,CREATED_DATETIME
    from OV80STG.PRCSD_DATA_OUTPUT_ARCHIVE
    where MODEL_CODE='MDLADV1538'
    AND TAG_VAL <> 'U_Transfer_rate'
      )   P
    WHERE
    (P.TAG_VALUE > '100')
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: remove the single quotes at `(P.TAG_VALUE > '100')`

Comment: @Arpit .  Can you check if the query  `SELECT *
  FROM OV80STG.PRCSD_DATA_OUTPUT_ARCHIVE
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(TAG_VALUE, '[^[:digit:]]')`  returns any rows?. It is to check if non-numeric characters exists in the column

Comment: Thanks for replying Jens, i have tried doing that but still the query returns same error.

Comment: @ Kaushik, thanks for your reply, yes the mentioned query is returning rows

Comment: @ArpitArora :  It means there are non-numeric characters in `TAG_VALUE`  column. You must replace them from all those records fetched.

Comment: @Kaushik - TAG_VALUE column is having text values from some other table and that is required, so if i have to perform arithmetic operation using TAG_VALUE column then do i need to change the data type of it to numeric? or is there some other workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Data type of column is not important here.extracting only numeric characters is.

Comment: I am extracting only numeric characters and then applying arithmetic operation on TAG_VALUE column but still i am getting error.

Comment: `TO_NUMBER()` does not convert non-numeric to numeric characters. It can read only numbers and extra characters such as "$" when used with proper format specifiers and nls modifiers.

Comment: I have used cast also but that too is giving error

Comment: If i add one more line to the code then it runs fine :-   SELECT DISTINCT
      count(P.CREATED_DATETIME)
    FROM
      ( 
      select OUTPUT_TAG_ID,TO_NUMBER(TAG_VAL,'9999.99') AS 
    TAG_VALUE,TAG_VAL_TS,CREATED_DATETIME
    from OV80STG.PRCSD_DATA_OUTPUT_ARCHIVE
    where MODEL_CODE='MDLADV1538'
    AND TAG_VAL <> 'U_Transfer_rate'
    AND output_tag_id =6201
      )   P
    WHERE
    (P.TAG_VALUE > '100')

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes from around the value in the `where`, you don't need them when its an integer. query will be like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(P.CREATED_DATETIME)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        OUTPUT_TAG_ID,
        TO_NUMBER(TAG_VAL, '9999.99') AS TAG_VALUE,
        TAG_VAL_TS,
        CREATED_DATETIME
    FROM OV80STG.PRCSD_DATA_OUTPUT_ARCHIVE
    WHERE MODEL_CODE = 'MDLADV1538'
          AND TAG_VAL <> 'U_Transfer_rate'
) P
WHERE(P.TAG_VALUE > 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @dbajtr, i have tried doing that but still the query returns same error.

Answer (score 0):

`TO_NUMBER` function returns a numeric value so, as mentioned in comment, you shouldn't compare it with string value.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by including outer `where` clause inside the subquery and then I got the required result without any error.